# What can be an appropriate notion of principal bundle over a category (with an appropriate notion of local trivialisation)?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, fibre-bundles, gauge-theory

**Motivation for my question:**

It is a well-known fact that there exists a bijection between the set of isomorphism class of
principal $G$ bundles over a nice topological space $X$ and the set $[X,B'G]$ of  homotopy class of continuous maps from $X$ to the classifying space $B'G$ (using the different notation than conventional for convenience) of the principal $G$-bundles.

Now let $X$ be a topological space and let $U=\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha}$ be a covering of $X$. Now it is also well known that the functor $\phi:C(U) \rightarrow BG$  from the Čech Groupoid $C(U)$ of the cover $U$ of $X$  to the delooping groupoid $BG$ of the topological group $G$ can be considered as a principal $G$ bundle over the space $X$.  (For example see definition 3.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7185.pdf).

If we move one step higher, that is a weak 2-functor from the Čech 2-groupoid $C^2(U)$ to the deloopoing $B^2G$  of a weak 2 group $G$ (*For definition of Čech 2-groupoid and delooping groupoid of weak 2-group please check example 2.20 and section 3.2 of* https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7185.pdf and *the definition of weak 2-group is found in*  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307200 )

then we arrive at the definition of Principal 2-bundle over the space $X$ where the structure 2-group is the weak 2 group $G$ (*see* definition 3.8 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7185.pdf) which I guess will be equivalent to the local description of *Christoph Wockel's definition of Principal 2 bundles in the definition 1.8 in* https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.3692. (*Though I did not check rigorously that they are indeed same*)

*Now motivated from the observations  above ,*

**My question is the following:**

**(1)** Is a weak 2-functor $F:C \rightarrow B^2G$ from a  category $C$(considered as a degenerate 2 category) to the delooping groupoid $B^2G$ of a weak 2-group $G$ can be a good choice of definition of principal bundle over a category where the structure group is the 2-group $G$?

Or

**(2)**  To get an appropriate notion of local trivialisation of a principal bundle over a category we have to somehow appropriately define the notion of Čech 2-groupoid $\tilde{Ch}(U)$ of a *"cover $U$ on the category $C$"* (may be coming from some Grothendieck pretopology on **Cat**, the  category of small categories) and then consider the 2- functor $\tilde{F}:\tilde{C}h(U) \rightarrow B^2G$ (where $\tilde{Ch}(U)$ is considered as a degenerate 2 category ) as a definition of locally trivializable  Principal 2-bundles over a category?

I could not find any literature where a notion of locally trivializable  *principal bundle over a general category* is explicitly mentioned. So any suggestion of literature in this direction will also be very helpful.

Also I am curious to know about its corresponding notion in higher categories and *in the context of infinity category*.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a Kan fibration with all fibres principal homogeneous $G$-spaces.  Take an $\infty$-category $C$ and a functor $C\to BG,$ where BG is the classifying groupoid of an $\infty$-group (a grouplike $E_1$-space).  Pulling back the overcategory projection $EG=BG_{/\ast}\to BG,$ where $\ast$ is the unique object of $BG$, gets you the Kan fibration you wanted.

A Kan fibration over a 1-category is a biCartesian fibration in groupoids, and being $G$-principal is a condition on the fibres.

To see this is the right condition, let $c$ be an object of $C$. Then $c$ is classified by a functor $\ast\to C,$ and the fibre over $c$ must be the pullback of $EG$ to a point, which is now just $\Omega BG\simeq G$ by recognizing $BG$ as the delooping of $G$.

Comment: In complete generality, being a principal G-space is an additional structure that has to be specified and checked to be compatible with the data in the fibration, but this is the rough gist of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Although I know very basics of infinity categories but I am curious to know whether the notion of local triviality in "Principal bundle over a category" is automatically followed from the notion you gave in the answer?

Comment: Please note I mentioned about local triviality in (2) in the question.

Comment: Local triviality doesn't really make sense homotopically/categorically.  It's not a fully homotopy-invariant property. The fact that this works for topological spaces is because you are working with nice spaces that have a close relationship between their topological and homotopical structure, somehow.

Comment: I can understand . But if I take a Grothendieck Pretopology on Cat then we can choose a  cover for the category $C$ with respect to the pretopology. Then if there is a notion of Cech Groupoid  $\tilde{Ch}(U)$ corresponding to this cover on $C$ and   if we consider a functor/2-functor $\tilde{Ch}(U) \rightarrow B^2G$ then what we are expecting to get? (Note here I am just using basic category theory with no notion of infinity category)

Comment: What does it mean to say "Local triviality doesn't really make sense homotopically/ categorically. It's not a fully homotopy-invariant property"? Does it mean one can find maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ that are homotopy equivalent such that $f$ is locally trivial in some sense, say locally trivial fibre bundle, but $g$ is not a locally trivial fibre bundle?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Any two points that are connected by a path are homotopically indistinguishable, so it destroys the topology.

Comment: @HarryGindi The statement "Any two points that are connected by a path are homotopically indistinguishable, so it destroys the topology" is acceptable, but, I do not see how that answers my question :O Can you elaborate how it answers my question?

Comment: @HarryGindi In response to your comment  " Any two points that are connected by a path are homotopically indistinguishable, so it destroys the topology."... but in that case we can talk about fundamental groupoid of the space..(which captures the information of 1st homotopy group and the path components of the space)... Then if  we have an appropriate notion of a locally trivial principal bundle over a path groupoid then I guess  we can expect that it will also capture a portion of  topological information present in a principal bundle over the original space.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri The fundamental groupoid can only see the locally constant sheaves on your space.  It's a special property of locally constant sheaves of sets that they can be reconstructed up to isomorphism from their homotopical data assuming that your original space is nice enough.

Comment: @HarryGindi Ok. But I guess the infinity groupoid (taking homotopy between homotopies and so on.....) contains a sufficient information for the reconstruction of the space upto weak equivalence (provided the space is a CW complex) .. Then why can't we have an appropriate notion of local triviality for a principal bundle over an infinity groupoid?

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri The property is just the property of being a Kan fibration.

Comment: @HarryGindi   Ok. Thank you. I am trying to understand.  But if you see the definition 2.12 ,2.13 ,2.14 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0412325.pdf  then is it not natural to expect a notion of locally trivial principal bundle over a general category? (I agree the fact that in this paper they have worked  only with categories internal to some generalised smooth spaces(like diffeological space or Chen space))...But can we expect to have an appropriate meaning of locally trivial principal bundle if we extend the notion from category int to smooth space to a general category?

Comment: @HarryGindi Please note these definitions are present in the section 2.2 in the page "contents" of the paper mentioned in the link(in the previous comment).  Thank you.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri Those are internal categories in $\mathbf{Diff}_\infty$, so they do carry a topology. These are much more complicated structures than what you are contemplating.

Comment: @HarryGindi Ok. That means you are saying we can expect a notion of local triviality in the case of categories internal to $Diff_{infty}$ because they carry a topology coming from its object set and morphism set. But for a general category there is no reason to expect such notion of local triviality... Am I right?

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri more or less.

Comment: @HarryGindi Thank you very much for your valuable comments.

Comment: @HarryGindi In the page 18 , in section 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0248.pdf they mention that local triviality can be understood in the context of higher geometry... Also in the last paragraph of the page  they mention that it's possible to have a notion of Principal bundle over a base groupoid or stack. Then according to the previous comments you made the notion of local triviality they are referring must be different from the usual one I have. Since I have very little background in infinity category it would be very helpful if you clarify "their" notion of "local triviality".

Comment: @HarryGindi Please note I assumed   that "they have assumed a notion of local triviality" when they talked about principal bundle over a groupoid or a stack in the last paragraph of the page 18 of the paper mentioned in the link(in the previous comment).

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri If you read more of the paper, they say that local triviality in their sense becomes automatic, which is what I said.  'As before, this means that the local triviality clause appearing in the traditional definition of principal bundles is not so much a characteristic of principality as such, as rather a condition that ensures that a given quotient taken in a category of geometric spaces coincides with the “refined” quotient obtained when regarding the situation in the ambient ∞-topos.' This will be my last message on the subject.

Comment: @HarryGindi Thank you very much for the explanation .